# Computer freezes while trying to load MNIST dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-management, computer-science, mnist

my computer specs:

[image: computer summary]

I was learning about classification in machine learning and encountered MNIST dataset.
I have to download it to run algorithms on it, but my computer just freezes every time I try to load it with this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
```

Do you guys know any way to download it on chunks or alternate dataset which doesn't require a lot of memory?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be an issue with your machine - but your pull may be stalling due to your version of `sklearn` / `openml`.  Without logs from the VM / container you're executing these commands from its hard to tell.

In the mean time, how about downloading the data via a web endpoint like [this one on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/avnishnish/mnist-original) or [this one on datahub](https://datahub.io/machine-learning/mnist_784).  The total size isn't large, and if you are successful you can at least eliminate your machine iteself as a point of failure.

Comment: huge Thanks brother . I downloaded the csv file, then stored it in pandas variable.

Comment: rock on - keep going!